# Bypassing SAFE CLR Managed Procedure limitation on DROP TABLE

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

I need advice on the best way of doing this.

Currently I have a clr procedure in MSSQL 2012 that bulk inserts a delimited data file into a temporary table it creates, then processes all the rows via various text/math logic into live data table.

Once its done, i would like to get rid of the table it created. DROP TABLE xxx is where I get the following error.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SyncAgents, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "SyncAgents": 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: ExternalThreading

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
   at StoredProcedures.SyncAgents()
.
```

Basically means it needs to be UNSAFE. Which is something I would like to avoid. So the question is:

What is the best way of dropping this table after I am done with it? Should it be a scheduled task? Is there some kind of clever trigger that can be set up to do it?

I am thinking of creating a scheduled procedure that looks in the queue (simple varchar/bit with tablename/isprocessed table) and then executes drops based on that queue.

Am I thinking of the problem wrong from the outset?

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Is this temp table a genuine temporary table (ie: beginning with #) or just a table you are using for temporary purposes?

Comment: Its a regular table. Should I use #table instead? I haven't looked at doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure (I'd put it as an answer if I were) but I'd give it a try - you're more likely to be able to delete that.

Comment: That worked beautifully, considering all i did was add # character to the beginning of the table name inside the clr sproc.

If you want to post your comment as an answer i'll mark it as answer to the question.

Comment: I'll write that as an answer then :)

Comment: Also I am given the same error if I try to delete #table but it should be dropped when its out of sproc context, am I corrent on that? So basically i am not explicitly deleting it.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works in terms of CLR procedures. You could always try a table variable, but I'm not sure if that will work with a BULK INSERT

Comment: Well it works fine with bulk insert. I was just curious if I need to drop the table explicitly once the procedure is done. But it appears that it should be automatically dropped when its out of context.

So technically you still can't drop that table explicitly, but you don't have to drop it if its a temporary table. Other than that its exactly same functionality when it comes to doing BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a proper temporary table (ie: one prefixed with a `#`) rather than a user table, you'll have the required permissions.